# Mysql56 for Windows does not recognize any new database

Tags: mysql, windows

As the title says, i have a fresh install of mysql56 server for Windows(currently installed on windows 8.1) and the server does not recognize any of my new databases. I've copied a pack of databases from a old hosting and just put them in the "data" directory of the server.

I've tried to restart mysql(process & service) but nothing changed.

Edit: I've created a new database with a new table but the server does not store the new database in the "data" folder. If the data is not stored in the Mysql/Data directory then where?

Comment: just having the files doesn't help. you need to actually TELL mysql the files are there. which means doing a `create database foo` for EVERY db you're trying to insert. And even then I'm not sure if that'll actually let you just drop the files in place, since mysql'll need to be told about the actual schemas in use in those files.

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to go.  But (like for virtually all databases), you must do some kind of explicit "export/import", or "migration".  You cannot simply copy the raw database files into a directory.

My preference is to use good old "mysqldump":

For example:

`mysqldump -u username -ppassword –all-databases > dump.sql`

You'd then restore on your new Windows install with a command like this:

`mysql -u username -ppassword database_name < dump.sql`

Here are more details:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/copying-databases.html

PS:
This tutorial shows you how to export/import with phpMyAdmin (even easier!):

http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/smb-technologist/import-and-export-databases-using-phpmyadmin/